# Can i use the same sanitize function on multiple theme mod textboxes?

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options, sanitization

I have a theme mod with multiple options and currently adding sanitizing options to those choices. This is my code I'm using:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'twsa_feed' , array(
'title'       => __( 'RSS Feed settings','rss_feed'),
'priority'    => 30,
'description' => 'Your RSS feed settings',
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'short-show-name' );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'short-show-name', array (
'label' => 'Show name',
'description' => 'Abbreviated show name, not the full name',
'section' => 'twsa_feed',
'type' => 'textbox',
'sanitize_callback' => 'twsa_sanitize_text',
));
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'show-category' );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'show-category', array (
'label' => 'Category',
'description' => 'What category does your show belong to? (not really important to stick to certain categories, can make one up)',
'section' => 'twsa_feed',
'type' => 'textbox',
'sanitize_callback' => 'twsa_sanitize_text',
));
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'author-name' );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'author-name', array (
'label' => 'Author name',
'description' => 'Must be a name',
'section' => 'twsa_feed',
'type' => 'textbox',
'sanitize_callback' => 'twsa_sanitize_text',
));
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'author-email' );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'author-email', array (
'label' => 'Author e-mail',
'description' => 'e-mail address',
'section' => 'twsa_feed',
'type' => 'textbox',
'sanitize_callback' => 'twsa_sanitize_text',
));
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'itunes-subtitle' );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'itunes-subtitle', array (
'label' => 'iTunes subtitle',
'description' => 'Short description of show',
'section' => 'twsa_feed',
'type' => 'textbox',
'sanitize_callback' => 'twsa_sanitize_text',
));
```

This is the function I use to sanitize the data:

```
function twsa_sanitize_text( $input ) {
return wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $input ) );
};
```

Is it OK to use one function to sanitize multiple text fields or do I need to create a function for each text field?

Thanks

Comment: your inputs are all the same (textbox) and most likely return the same type of data ( some human-readable text ), so i don't think you need different functions. One will do it all, unless you have checkbox, radio buttons, HTML input, etc.

Comment: Of course it's ok! If they're all sanitized in the same way, then that's exactly the intention of a function - reuse.

Comment: Can one of you move your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see, your inputs are all the same (textbox) and most likely return the same type of data ( some human-readable text ), so i don't think you need different functions.

One will do it all, unless you have checkbox, radio buttons, HTML input, etc which might need different types of sanitation (such as allowing some special HTML tags).